# Error when setting a blank pivot table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to creat a pivot table with a distinct count of a values in "Number" column. First rows of my data looks like this:

[image]

So I want a pivot table that looks like this:

| Number | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |

Right now I have written a code to creat one but I've got an error when Inserting a blank Pivot table. I'm trying to make this pivot table for hours, so I will be really greatful for any help.

My code (I know I didn't set a values, but right know I'm trying to figure out an error with blank pivot table):

```
Sub Zadanie3()
'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "A").Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)


'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Number")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: Aleksandra, in my answer I just added the Value field and I know you mentioned that you just didn't add that because you're trying to figure out why you can't generated the PivotTable. As I got no error, it is probably not a problem with your code given the information that you shared. I could not replicate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code is generating a Pivot on my end with no problems, but not necessarily the way you wanted (there is no Value field with the Count of 'Number') as you described. So I suggest to double check if your file is set up correctly, restart excel, or create another file as a test.

To generate the desired table with "Number" in rows field and Count of "Number" in value field, add the Value field before the Row field:

```
Sub Zadanie3_with_Count()
'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "A").Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables _
        ("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Number"), "Count", xlCount

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Number")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Number"

End Sub
```